# Comprobar en que Activity estoy

Tags: java, android

Tengo este `Button` en mi `Adapter` de `RecyclerView` y cuando hago clic en el debe actualizar mi `RecyclerView` con el metodo `ActualizarRecyclerView`

```
    holder.delete_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabase.deleteNotas(singleNotas.getId());

            ActualizaRecyclerView();
            ActualizaRecyclerViewDiaria();
            ActualizaRecyclerViewSemanal();
            ActualizaRecyclerViewMensual();
            ActualizaRecyclerViewFavorito();

        }
    });
```

El problema es que cada método sirve para una `Activity` distinta, por ejemplo:

```
ActualizarRecyclerView = MainActivity

ActualizarRecyclerView = MainActivity2

...
```

Por lo tanto, necesito algo similar a comprobar en que `Activity` estoy haciendo clic en el botón para así ejecutar ese método, sino recibo **null** al no estar en esa `Activity`.

Mi idea ha sido esa, comprobar en que `Activity` estoy para así ejecutar ese método, pero si tenéis una solución mejor, bienvenida sea!

Gracias :)

**EDITO1:**

Cuando hago clic en `cardview_item` lo que hace es mostrar un icono en `CardView`, y si vuelvo a hacer clic ocultarlo.

`Adapter`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NotasViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);

    holder.icon_fav.setVisibility(singleNotas.getFavorito().equals("")? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

    holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabase.FavNotas(singleNotas.getId());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
           //ActualizaRecyclerView();

        }
    });
}
```

El método `FavNotas` está en mi `Sqlite`:

```
   public void FavNotas(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_FAVORITO + " FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String val = "";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, val);
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
        if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FAVORITO)).equals("favorito"))
        {
            val = "favorito";
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            values2.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, val);
            db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values2, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
        }

        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
        values1.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, val);
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values1, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    }
```

El problema, es que cuando hago clic se realiza la acción pero no se actualiza mi `RecyclerView` y no se ve el cambio hasta que salgo y entro en la `Activity`, por lo tanto lo que se me ocurrió fue crear un método para actualizar `RecyclerView`:

```
 public static void ActualizaRecyclerView() {
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());

        allNotas = (ArrayList<Notas>) mDatabase.listNotas();

        if (allNotas.size() > 0) {
            RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerview_notas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAdapter = new NotasAdapter(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext(), allNotas);
            mAdapter_d.filter("");
            recyclerview_notas.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerview_notas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Tengo el mismo `RecyclerView` en diferentes `Activity` pero con `mAdapter_filter("");` distinto, por lo tanto cuando hago clic en `cardview_item`, según en que `Activity` estoy, necesito que utilice un `ActualizarRecyclerView` u otro, no sé como hacer uno "universal" para que se actualice en cualquier `Activity` pero respetando el `mAdapter_filter("")`

**EDITO2:**

Esto es lo que ocurre, al principio parece ir bien, pero cuando hago varias veces clic:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`Adapter`

```
public class NotasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotasAdapter.NotasViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Notas> listNotas;
    private SqliteDatabase mDatabase;

    public NotasAdapter(Context context, List<Notas> listNotas) {
        this.context = context;
        Collections.reverse(listNotas);
        this.listNotas = (ArrayList<Notas>) listNotas;
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(context);
    }

    @Override
    public NotasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notas_list_adapter, parent, false);
        return new NotasViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NotasViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);

        holder.icon_fav.setVisibility(singleNotas.getFavorito().equals("")? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

        holder.edit_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(context, EditarNota.class);
                intent.putExtra("editNotas", singleNotas);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        holder.delete_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //delete row from database
                mDatabase.deleteNotas(singleNotas.getId());
             //
                listNotas.remove(position);
                //una ves removido el item, se notifican los cambios para que se actualize la lista
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                /*((Activity)context).finish();
                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());*/

            }
        });
        holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDatabase.FavNotas(singleNotas.getId());

                //actualizas el icono, o los elementos que quieras
                if(singleNotas.getFavorito().equals("")){
                    singleNotas.setFavorito("favorito");
                }
                else{
                    singleNotas.setFavorito("");
                }
                //usas este para notificar cambios solo en una posicion de la lista
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listNotas.size();
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo la perculiralidad de tener un diseño así, talvez debes replantear el enfoque.

Comment: ¿ El Adapter es el que usas en tus anteriores preguntas ? La respuesta de @Carmen te seria  util, cambiando el `this` por el contexto que puedes pasar en el constructor del adapter, no obstante, tienes la magia de `notifyDataSetChanged`, cuando el usuario presione eliminar en esa nota, de tu ArrayList eliminas el item con esa posición, y notificas los cambios, estos se actualizaran sin importar la clase en la que estés. Voy a buscar tu Adapter y elaborar una respuesta de lo que me refiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi propuesta es que cuando se clique en el botón de eliminar un elemento, lo elimines como ya haces de tu SQL, y en vez de "rehacer" la lista con los nuevos datos llamando al metodo segun su nombre, elimines de tu `List` el elemento y notifiques los cambios de esta manera:

```
holder.delete_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mDatabase.deleteNotas(singleNotas.getId());

        // position es la posición del item seleccionado
        // tuLista es la lista que datos que estas usando en el adapter
        tuLista.remove(position);
        //una ves removido el item, se notifican los cambios para que se actualize la lista
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

EDITO:

Si al hacer click en un elemento quieres cambiar algo, basta con hacerlo como si fuera un objeto normal, no es necesario notificar los cambios. ¿Porque si te funciona el método? Porque construyes un adapter nuevo y lo asignas. ¿porque no funciona notificar los cambios en tu adapter? Cuando lo haces, la clase del adapter esta usando los mismos datos que contenía, por lo que si no han sido alterados en el `List` recargara lo que tenia cuando se abrio.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NotasViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);

    holder.icon_fav.setVisibility(singleNotas.getFavorito().equals("")? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

    holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabase.FavNotas(singleNotas.getId());

            //actualizas el icono, o los elementos que quieras
            if(holder.icon_fav.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                holder.icon_fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                holder.icon_fav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Otra manera de hacerlo si quieres hacerlo notificando los cambios:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NotasViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);

    holder.icon_fav.setVisibility(singleNotas.getFavorito().equals("")? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

    holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabase.FavNotas(singleNotas.getId());

            //actualizas el icono, o los elementos que quieras
            if(singleNotas.getFavorito().equals("")){
                singleNotas.setFavorito("favorito");
            }
            else{
                singleNotas.setFavorito("");
            }
            //usas este para notificar cambios solo en una posicion de la lista
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
}
```

EDITO 2:
Seguramente vas a tener el problema que al hacer scroll, los elementos previamente alterados, regresan a la posición inicial.
Esto se debe a que Android, destruye los elementos que no son visibles para recrearlos. Para solucionar eso, en tu `Adapter` sobrescribe el metodo `getItemViewType`:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Te explico, cuando usas un adaptar, aun usándolo en distintas pantallas, son "independientes" es decir que si realizas una acción sobre uno de ellos, sera ese el que cambie y no el resto, por lo que no necesitas crear una acción para cada activity. Ahora mi pregunta, lo que buscas es que al hacer click en el `cardview_item` cambie una imagen y se actualice ?

Comment: Si, sencillamente realiza los cambios al elemento como si no existiera un adapter, ademas de actualizar la SQL. Notificar los cambios se utiliza al modificar los elementos de la lista, pero si ya están cargados basta con manipularlos. Edito mi respuesta

Comment: Si, se actualiza porque recreas el adapter, el problema es cuando haces scroll ? he editado agregando la solución a eso. No obstante, `holder` contiene cada fila que se esta usando, cuando tu haces click en el cardview, el holder contiene ese elemento de la fila, asi como la imagen, texto... por lo que no debería de estar fallando. ¿Que ocurre exactamente al hacer click en el segundo de la lista?

Comment: Haga clic en la posición que lo haga, siempre se oculta/muestra el icono en el de la primera posición. Por cierto, borre comentarios para que no nos echen al chat automáticamente.

Comment: Tal vez en el chat era mas rapido xd, realmente no le veo mucho sentido a que te modifique solo la primera, lo he probado antes de postearlo y no he tenido ningún problema. Voy a agregar otra manera que podrías probar, si tampoco funciona coloca el Adapter para ver que es lo que esta llendo mal

Comment: Nada, sigue sin ir bien, he añadido el `adapter` y un *GIF* para que puedas ver como se vuelve loco jaja

Comment: Al eliminar un elemento esta funcionando bien ? haz que te imprima en el Logcat "position" realmente no veo nada mal, pero si puedes eliminar el static de tu lista: `public ArrayList<Notas> listNotas;` eso podría causar problemas si por ejemplo inflas dos listas usando ese adapter. Y en tu activity, haces algo en el listener de cada fila ? `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener`

Comment: No estoy utilizando `addOnItemTouchListener` ya quite el `static` pero sigue igual, me imprime bien la posición, así que no sé dónde puede estar fallando..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61066/discussion-between-israel-and-usernameyo).

Comment: Añade a la pregunta que no se debe utilizar `static` en el botón xd ! Marco como solución! Gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Si estás en `oncreate`:

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Sino específica el nombre de la clase en lugar de `this`.

Otra opción es declarar un objeto con una variable con sus métodos `get` y `set`, y setear el valor en la actividad, de modo que dicho valor será el de la última actividad activa.